# How to include qml file from js file

Tags: javascript, qml

I collect [some examples](https://github.com/drzhbe/QmlTxt/blob/master/Import.md) of `import` statement in QML. But one is lacking — import a qml file from js file.

Documentation [says](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-imports.html#importing-a-qml-module-from-a-javascript-resource) that it is a way to do it

```
.import Qt.test 1.0 as JsQtTest
```

but I can't make it work.
I appreciate suggestions on my example collection and the answer to the question — how to import qml file from js file?

Comment: JsQtTest is not defined

Comment: It works for some other library?

Comment: No, I never succeed to import qml file from js

Comment: Which Qt/QML version?

Comment: Did you define "Qt.test" module?

Comment: Go to link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850881/styling-qml-without-manually-marking-each-property-to-be-styled

Comment: @QtRoS what do you mean by define? Did you successfully import qml into js?

Comment: @Serkilinc why? It is about import js into qml and there is no problem. The problem is in reversed situation — import qml into js.

Comment: Same does not work for me (using Qt 5.6.1), is it a bug in Qt?

Comment: Have you found the solution/workaround of the issue?

Comment: @gerichhome no solution. We workarounded this issue as you did, but later we decided to not use JS files at all.

Answer (score 1):

One possible workaround for the issue I think is to do not import Qt library inside JS file but instead pass it as a parameter to the function exported from JS file:

```
function initLibrary(JsQtTest) {
   return {
      foo: function() {
         // use JsQtTest here
      }
   };
}
```

in QML you would write something like this:

```
import "myLibrary.js" as LibraryFactory
import Qt.test 1.0 as JsQtTest
...

var lib = LibraryFactory.initLibrary(JsQtTest)

lib.foo();
```

Comment: Yes, thats the way I do it, but wanted to know more legal way. This is not a way if you want a js singleton.